# Java regex match characters outside Basic Multilingual Plane

Tags: java, regex, unicode, astral-plane

How can I match characters (with the intention of removing them) from outside the unicode Basic Multilingual Plane in java?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To remove all non-BMP characters, the following should work:

```
String sanitizedString = inputString.replaceAll("[^\u0000-\uFFFF]", "");
```

Comment: Have you actually tested this? Because your character range includes the surrogate range used to construct non-BMP codepoints.

Comment: @Anon: As you pointed out in your own answer, regexps are evaluated at the level of codepoints, not codeunits, so it doesn't see surrogates.

Comment: Yes, this has been tested with non-BMP characters.

Comment: @axtavt - actually, I assumed that regex was evaluated at the character level, and that the non-BMP codepoint was simply translated into surrogates.

Comment: @Anon - More info on supplementary characters in java: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/Supplementary/

Comment: WARNING: this substitution may introduce new astral characters by pairing previously unpaired surrogates, which may or may not be acceptable for the original question: try `String inputString = "\uD800\uD800\uDC00\uDC00";`.

Comment: Side note #1: for `\uD800\uD800\uDC00\uDC00` example @Anon's `StringBuilder` solution produces exactly the same output as regex solution. Side note #2: applying this filtering twice (or more) may be required to ged rid of non-BMP chars completely.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for specific characters or all characters outside the BMP?

If the former, you can use a `StringBuilder` to construct a string containing code points from the higher planes, and regex will work as expected:

```
  String test = new StringBuilder().append("test").appendCodePoint(0x10300).append("test").toString();
  Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint(0x10300).toString());

  Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(test);
  matcher.find();
  System.out.println(matcher.start());
```

If you're looking to remove *all* non-BMP characters from a string, then I'd use `StringBuilder` directly rather than regex:

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(test.length());
  for (int ii = 0 ; ii < test.length() ; )
  {
     int codePoint = test.codePointAt(ii);
     if (codePoint > 0xFFFF)
     {
        ii += Character.charCount(codePoint);
     }
     else
     {
        sb.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
        ii++;
     }
  }
```