# java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\xBD\xF0\x9F...'

Tags: java, mysql, encoding, character-encoding, sqlexception

I have the following string value: "walmart obama "

I am using MySQL and Java.

I am getting the following exception: `java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\xBD\xF0\x9F...'

Here is the variable I am trying to insert into:

```
var1 varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL`
```

My Java code that is trying to insert "walmart obama " is a preparedStatement. So I am using the `setString()` method.

It looks like the problem is the encoding of the values . How can I fix this? Previously I was using Derby SQL and the values  just ended up being two sqaures (I think this is the representation of the null character)

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc/10959780

Comment: When you create the database, you can give the character set and collation like this: `CREATE DATABASE db_name CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
`

Answer (score 157):

What you have is [`EXTRATERRESTRIAL ALIEN (U+1F47D)`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f47d/index.htm) and [`BROKEN HEART (U+1F494)`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f494/index.htm) which
are not in the basic multilingual plane. They cannot be even represented in java as one char, `"".length() == 4`. They are definitely not null characters and one will see squares if you are not using fonts that support them.

[MySQL's `utf8` only supports basic multilingual plane, and you need to use `utf8mb4` instead](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html):

> For a supplementary character, utf8 cannot store the character at all,
>   while utf8mb4 requires four bytes to store it. Since utf8 cannot store
>   the character at all, you do not have any supplementary characters in
>   utf8 columns and you need not worry about converting characters or
>   losing data when upgrading utf8 data from older versions of MySQL.

So to support these characters, your MySQL needs to be 5.5+ and you need to use `utf8mb4` everywhere. Connection encoding needs to be `utf8mb4`, character set needs to be `utf8mb4` and collaction needs to be `utf8mb4`. For java it's still just `"utf-8"`, but MySQL needs a distinction.

I don't know what driver you are using but a driver agnostic way to set connection charset is to send the query:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'
```

Right after making the connection.

[See also this for Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-troubleshooting.html):

> 14.14: How can I use 4-byte UTF8, utf8mb4 with Connector/J?
>
> To use 4-byte UTF8 with Connector/J configure the MySQL server with
>   character_set_server=utf8mb4. Connector/J will then use that setting
>   *as long as characterEncoding has **not** been set in the connection
>   string*. This is equivalent to autodetection of the character set.

Adjust your columns and database as well:

```
var1 varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL
```

Again, your MySQL version needs to be relatively up-to-date for utf8mb4 support.

Comment: Check out my other related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748170/jdbc-mysql-collation-settings. If you can answer it, then you will have answered this question as well. The other post has more details of what I have done.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus have you changed everything in your database to `utf8mb4`, it looks like you are still using `utf8_general_ci`..

Comment: I have changed everything in my database. I believe the error comes from Java. I'll post the details tomorrow, I am having trouble connection to my database right now...

Comment: Don't do "SET NAMES" with Connector/J: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html `Do not issue the query set names with Connector/J, as the driver will not detect that the character set has changed, and will continue to use the character set detected during the initial connection setup. `

Comment: In case you want to just get rid of the characters from outside the BMP instead of dealing with the mess of changing your DB, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035562/java-regex-match-characters-outside-basic-multilingual-plane

Comment: I have the same problem, followed the steps above but didn't get resolved till changed the character-set-server=utf8mb4 in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini

Comment: I used utf8-mb4 for long text and I was tiring to store 'beta' character,  this solution (SET NAMES 'utf8mb4') was useful for me, Thanks

Comment: A strongly suggest to add this addition from the [latest version of Connector/J FAQ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-troubleshooting.html#qandaitem-15-1-14): `For 5.1.47 and later: You can use characterEncoding=UTF-8 to use utf8mb4, even if character_set_server on the server has been set to something else.` This helps when you can't or don't want to change `character_set_server` in your MySQL server instance.

Answer (score 21):

Weirdly, I found that REMOVING `&characterEncoding=UTF-8` from the `JDBC url` did the trick for me with similar issues.

Based on my properties,

```
jdbc_url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName?useUnicode=true
```

I think this supports what @Esailija has said above, i.e. my MySQL, which is indeed 5.5, is figuring out its own favorite flavor of UTF-8 encoding.

(Note, I'm also specifying the `InputStream` I'm reading from as `UTF-8` in the java code, which probably doesn't hurt)...

Comment: Maybe `useUnicode=true` isn't even needed?   In my case the only thing that worked is setting `character_set_server=utf8mb4` globally on the server (RDS parameter group) and *NOT* having any characterEncoding in the JDBC URL.

Answer (score 17):

All in all, to save symbols that require 4 bytes you need to update characher-set and collation for `utf8mb4`:

1. database table/column:
   `alter table <some_table> convert to character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
2. database server connection ([see](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-server.html))

On my development enviromnt for #2 I prefer to set parameters on command line when starting the server:
`mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

---

btw, pay attention to [Connector/J behavior](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html) with `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'`:

> Do not issue the query set names with Connector/J, as the driver will not detect that the character set has changed, and will continue to use the character set detected during the initial connection setup.

And avoid setting `characterEncoding` parameter in connection url as it will override configured server encoding:

> To override the automatically detected encoding on the client side, use the characterEncoding property in the URL used to connect to the server.

Answer (score 7):

How I solved my problem.

I had

```
?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

In my hibernate jdbc connection url and I changed the string datatype to longtext in database, which was varchar before.

Comment: Greate if you dont need that column indexed and its relatively small, but i can do this trick for all my columns though

Answer (score 4):

Append the line `useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8` to your jdbc url.

In your case the data is not being send using `UTF-8` encoding.

Comment: How do I append this? In my connection string? I am using Netbeans if that helps.

Comment: How are you creating the connection?

Comment: DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:####/[dbName]", [user name], [password]);

Comment: Do it like this - DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:####/[dbName]?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8", [user name], [password]);

Comment: Scratch that, I forgot the '?' But now I am back to the same error as the original post...

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue and solved it by setting the **Collation** to **utf8_general_ci** for each column.

Answer (score 2):

I guess MySQL doesn't believe this to be valid UTF8 text. I tried an insert on a test table with the same column definition (mysql client connection was also UTF8) and although it did the insert, the data I retrieved with the MySQL CLI client as well as JDBC didn't retrieve the values correctly. To be sure UTF8 did work correctly, I inserted an "ö" instead of an "o" for obama:

```
johan@maiden:~$ mysql -vvv test < insert.sql 
--------------
insert into utf8_test values(_utf8 "walmart öbama ")
--------------

Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.12 sec)

johan@maiden:~$ file insert.sql 
insert.sql: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Small java application to test with:

```
package test.sql;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("test string=" + "walmart öbama ");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://hostname/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");
            PreparedStatement p = c.prepareStatement("select * from utf8_test");
            p.execute();
            ResultSet rs = p.getResultSet();
            while (!rs.isLast())
            {
                rs.next();
                String retrieved = rs.getString(1);
                System.out.println("retrieved=\"" + retrieved + "\"");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
johan@appel:~/workspaces/java/javatest/bin$ java test.sql.Test
test string=walmart öbama 
retrieved="walmart öbama "
```

Also, I've tried the same insert with the JDBC connection and it threw the same exception you are getting.
I believe this to be a MySQL bug. Maybe there's a bug report about such a situation already..

Comment: By the way, the characters in your string don't even show up correctly in both Firefox and Chrome on OSX. They do show up correctly in my iTerm application. I think this is font dependent.

Answer (score 1):

I had kind of the same problem and after going carefully against all charsets and finding that they were all right, I realized that the bugged property I had in my class was annotated as @Column instead of @JoinColumn (javax.presistence; hibernate) and it was breaking everything up.

Answer (score 1):

execute

```
show VARIABLES like "%char%”;
```

find character-set-server if is not utf8mb4.

set it in your my.cnf, like

```
vim /etc/my.cnf
```

add one line

```
character_set_server = utf8mb4
```

at last restart mysql

Comment: `character_set_server` is the option, NOT `character-set-server`

Answer (score 0):

This setting useOldUTF8Behavior=true worked fine for me. It gave no incorrect string errors but it converted special characters like Ã into multiple characters and saved in the database.

To avoid such situations, I removed this property from the JDBC parameter and instead converted the datatype of my column to BLOB. This worked perfect.

Comment: Could you please add more deatil to your answer? (code, commants, etc.)

Answer (score -4):

Besides,data type can use blob install of varchar or text.

Comment: You do not want that