# java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr...'

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, sqlexception

I have code looking like that:

```
    @Column(name = COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
private Map<Locale, String> description = new HashMap<>();
```

after trying to add something to column i got

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr...' for column 'description' at row 1
```

Where's the problem?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653712/java-sql-sqlexception-incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x91-xbd-xf0-x9f

Comment: You need to show what you are adding to the column.

Comment: Add the table structure that you have created, show COLUMN_DESCRIPTION information the error is there you have to specify proeper keywords there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it so here it is, maybe someone find it useful:

I tried to use `columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT"` in wrong place. There's only reference to table `ProductLocalization`, where mulitilingual descriptions are stored. When I used

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = AbstractLocalizingEntity.COLUMN_RELATED_ENTITY, nullable = false)
private Product entity;

@Column(name = Product.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
private String description;
```

in `ProductLocalization` class it started working fine. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Surely it is a MYSQL Bug ... More can be seen at http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=59456

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary a bug. You may try store this object as a blob. Which is a data type in e.g. mysql