# Exception java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\xBC' for column 'Rins' at row 1 at

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
2014-05-14 08:41:02
Error in : org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1215)
org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1148)
org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1154)
org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:695)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor193.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.merge(Unknown Source)
com.REP.CompanyAcce.pat.dao.BaseDAO.save(BaseDAO.java:50)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor250.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.save(Unknown Source)
com.REP.CompanyAcce.pat.service.PATThreadService.saveCandidatesData(PATThreadService.java:561)
com.REP.CompanyAcce.pat.service.PATThreadService.collectCandidateData(PATThreadService.java:200)
com.REP.CompanyAcce.pat.service.PATThreadService$CollectCandidateDataThread.run(PATThreadService.java:90)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.REP.CompanyAcce.pat.entity.PATCandidatesData]javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.REP.CompanyAcce.pat.entity.PATCandidatesData] at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1215) at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1148) at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1154) at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:695) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor193.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.merge(Unknown Source) at com.REP.CompanyAcce.pat.dao.BaseDAO.save(BaseDAO.java:50) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor250.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.save(Unknown Source) at com.REP.CompanyAcce.pat.service.PATThreadService.saveCandidatesData(PATThreadService.java:561) at com.REP.CompanyAcce.pat.service.PATThreadService.collectCandidateData(PATThreadService.java:200) at com.REP.CompanyAcce.pat.service.PATThreadService$CollectCandidateDataThread.run(PATThreadService.java:90) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.REP.CompanyAcce.pat.entity.PATCandidatesData] at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140) at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128) at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66) at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64) at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2345) at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2852) at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71) at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273) at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320) at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203) at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129) at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3MergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3MergeEventListener.java:62) at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:415) at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.mergeTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:341) at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:303) at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:258) at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:84) at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:867) at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:851) at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:855) at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:686) ... 23 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\xBC' for column 'HEADLINE' at row 1 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3603) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3535) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1989) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2150) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626) at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119) at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2415) at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2333) at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2318) at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:493) at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94) at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57) ... 40 more
```

I created table like this:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `aa`;   

CREATE TABLE  `aa` (
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Rins` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then

> ALTER TABLE aa MODIFY Rins VARCHAR(45)  CHARACTER SET UTF8
>       COLLATE utf8_polish_ci;

But still I am getting Exception

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value:
>   '\xF0\x9F\x92\xBC' for column 'Rins' at row 1 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQL

Comment: ` '\xF0\x9F\x92\xBC'` is not UTF-8

Comment: '\xF0\x9F\x92\xBC' is Encoding . Real text may be something different.

Comment: Show relevant source code and data you insert.

Comment: so what happens when you try to insert a normal polish word into the table?

Comment: It's Excel sheet. In which I have to give 4 position. Firstname, Lastname, Email, LinkedInURL

Answer (score 6):

I guess you're only using utf-8.

In your CREATE TABLE try this...

```
`Rins` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL
```

utf-8 only supports [Basic Multilingual Planes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)
wherein your special characters do not belong. So you have to use utf8mb4 instead

and your Mysql should be 5.5+

this thread can give you more explanation... [java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\xBD\xF0\x9F…'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653712/java-sql-sqlexception-incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x91-xbd-xf0-x9f)

Comment: I am using Mysql 5.5 so can i get solution for that ??

Comment: Yes... it's here [Mysql-Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html)

Answer (score 0):

The character the error refers to "U+1F4BC" is a supplemental character not supported by utf8 in mysql. [You should try using utf8mb4 instead.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html)

> For a supplementary character, utf8 cannot store the character at all, while utf8mb4 requires four bytes to store it. Since utf8 cannot store the character at all, you do not have any supplementary characters in utf8 columns and you need not worry about converting characters or losing data when upgrading utf8 data from older versions of MySQL.