# “Incorrect string value” when trying to insert String into MySQL via Python and Text file

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8

What is causing this incorrect string? I have read many questions and answers and here are my results. I still am getting same error after reading answers.

I am getting the following error:
`ERROR 1366 (HY000) at line 34373: Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBB\xBF<?x...' for column 'change' at row 1`

When I try to enter the following into SQL:
Line number 34373: `INSERT INTO gitlog_changes VALUES ('123456', 'NhincCommonEntity.xsd', '﻿<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>');`

My table looks like this:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gitlog_changes`;
CREATE TABLE `gitlog_changes` (
  `hashID` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(450) DEFAULT NULL,
  `change` mediumtext
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I read many answers that say change the charset to UTF8 [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670754/exception-java-sql-sqlexception-incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x92-xbc-for)[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc)[[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108824/mysql-incorrect-string-value-error-when-save-unicode-string-in-django). So I execute this:
`alter table yourTableName DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;`

I continue to get the same error. Then I `alter table yourTableName DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4_general_ci;`

Still same error occurs.

I also attempt to read in a file from python and do direct commits to the database. From this answer[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors). I get a warning instead of an error.

I insert the following code into my python script:

```py
    cursor.execute("SET NAMES 'utf8'")
    cursor.execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8")
```

Python script:

```py
def insert_changes(modList):
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "user", "password", "table")
    cursor = db.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SET NAMES 'utf8'")
    cursor.execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8")

    for mod in modList:
        hashID = mod["hashID"]
        fileName = mod["fileName"]
        change = mod["change"]

        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO gitlog_changes VALUES (%s, %s, %s" , (hashID, fileName, change))
    # # disconnect from server
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

The warning I get here is: `Warning: Invalid utf8 character string: '\xEF\xBB\xBF<?x...'
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO gitlog_changes VALUES (%s, %s, %s)" , (hashID, fileName, change))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string you're trying to insert into db has an unusual character at its beginning. I just copied your string:

```
In [1]: a = '<'

In [2]: a
Out[2]: '\xef\xbb\xbf<'
```

You need to get rid of those characters. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159118/incorrect-string-value-xef-xbf-xbd-for-column) is a good post explaining what these characters are.

Answer (score 2):

Text you're trying to insert contains [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in the beginning (that's the **\xEF\xBB\xBF** in your error).

Please [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590749/reading-unicode-file-data-with-bom-chars-in-python) to see how to convert from UTF-8 with BOM into UTF-8.

---

As stated in [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode.html)

> MySQL uses no BOM for UTF-8 values.

So the only solution is decoding this string in your python code.

Comment: What do I change in the database?

Comment: @Whitecat As I mentioned in edit, the only way is to decode the string inside your python code

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. All strings need to be edited to put them into SQL. I even have to edit the insert statements from the file if I want to use the file.

Comment: The reason I avoided decode and encode is this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors says it is a bad idea.

Comment: Arg. I get the error `'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 77: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: @Whitecat Ok, I added a link to an answer how to read a string in utf-8 bom encoding, this should remove the bom bytes from the string. I didn't know it differs that much from reading utf-16 bom :)