# Twitter Text from Java to MySQL: utf8mb4 SQL Error "reportcharsetnr("

Tags: java, mysql, twitter, utf8mb4

For context: Trying to load Twitter Text into a MySQL DB. Some Tweets have `utf8mb4` characters which throws a *java.SQL.Exception*. I solved this and thanks to [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653712/java-sql-sqlexception-incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x91-xbd-xf0-x9f)

Now, the Java code runs with no errors; however, I can't perform a simple `select * from test.tweet` on my table.

I get the following SQL Error:

> Error Code: 0 45) . Please reportcharsetnr (

**SQL Code:**

```
create table test.tweet (
    text varchar(200) character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci not null);
```

**Java Code:** *(I know this works)*

```
// create a mysql database connection
        String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?";
        Class.forName(myDriver).newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "pass");
        PreparedStatement setNames = conn.prepareStatement("SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'");
        setNames.execute();

//Load the tweets into a mySQL DB
                    loadTweets(jsonObject, conn);
```

There is NOTHING on the internet about this error. Any thoughts why I can't query this error message:

> **Error Code: 0 45) . Please reportcharsetnr (**
>   [image: MySQL error message]

Comment: I actually solved my own question and I want to provide the answer despite a low reputation, as I think this is unique. First, I had to delete the entire SCHEMA. Second, I executed the SQL Statement: set names 'utf8mb4'.  Third, I created a table: CREATE table test.test (id primary key not null, text varchar(64) charset utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci) character set utf8mb4. FOURTH, every time I want execute my Java PreparedStatement, I actually execute a "set names 'utf8mb4' immediately prior (as seen above)....that's it. hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL Workbench i get that error too when i run `SET NAMES` without collation.

I fix it executing (change the collation properly):

```
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' collate 'utf8mb4_spanish_ci';
```

You can execute it in your code after creating the connection.

Comment: I used this variation of @aanton's answer, which worked in my case:

SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';

Comment: @AaronReed be careful, chartset "utf8" in MySQL does not include 4-byte UTF-8 characters, you should use "utf8mb4"

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error after I created and attempted to work with a database in MySQL Workbench. After I restarted Workbench my problem disappeared.