# Issue with Character Set encoding for Emojis when using Mysql and Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, encoding, utf-8, emoji

I have an application coded with Spring/Hibernate/Spring Data/ Jpa

When I try to update an entity , I am getting this error :

```
[ERROR] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Incorrect string value: '\xEF\x83\xA8 Be...' for column 'description' at row 1
```

What characterset should I use in Mysql in order to get rid of this problem?

Thank you

Comment: I think your String containing some emoji symbol. For that reason it is throwing that exception. Please see the similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653712/java-sql-sqlexception-incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x91-xbd-xf0-x9f

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `utf8mb4` MySQL Character Set which has also become [the default one in MySQL 8](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-when-to-use-utf8mb3-over-utf8mb4/).

Quoting the MySQL Server team post, if you want to use Emojis, then you need the `utf8mb4` Character Set.

> Even for English speaking markets, the prevalence of emojis as
> character input is driving adoption of utf8mb4 over utf8mb3 and
> latin1.

You can set the `utf8mb4` Character Set using the following `ALTER DATABASE` SSL statement:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: it's not for emojis in my case, it appears when I copy/paste a PDF or MS word document into a Varchar column in mysql. The content of MS Word contains special characters. Maybe this solution works in that case too

Comment: Make sure you read the MS Word doc using the input source encoding and extract data in UTF8. Then, use only UTF8 from your app to the DB.