# Spring Boot and Mysql : Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\x96 like...' for column 'description' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

this  is my first question here. I'm suffering from this error after reading 100s of blogs I'm getting anywhere.
I'm using **Intelij21.x, Gradle 7.X and Mysql 8.x, and Spring Boot 2.7.x.**.
I'm getting this error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
and
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\x92s sal...' for column 'description' at row 1

**Stack Trace**

```
Hibernate: insert into MediaContentVariantEntity (dateCreated, lastUpdated, description, language, title, video_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2022-09-01 14:12:06.502  WARN 15220 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1366, SQLState: HY000
2022-09-01 14:12:06.502 ERROR 15220 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Incorrect string value: '\x96 like...' for column 'description' at row 1
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source)
    at com.enveu.saas.service.ContentMigrationService.migrate(ContentMigrationService.java:453)
    at com.enveu.saas.BytearkDataMigrationApplication.run(BytearkDataMigrationApplication.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.enveu.saas.BytearkDataMigrationApplication.main(BytearkDataMigrationApplication.java:41)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement

    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3279)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3885)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:780)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:510)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:543)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:437)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:666)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:681)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor97.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alpha_4_1661946202334?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

**SHOW CREATE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE `mediacontentvariantentity` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dateCreated` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastUpdated` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `language` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `video_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKbeymct73p5lhak2h3ln3wxkcc` (`video_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKbeymct73p5lhak2h3ln3wxkcc` FOREIGN KEY (`video_id`) REFERENCES `videocontententity` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=169 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

Comment: Does this answer of your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653712/java-sql-sqlexception-incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x91-xbd-xf0-x9f?

Comment: no, I'm using mysql8.0.30 and encoding of column database and table is utf8mb4 and collation is utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, and added ?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8 still getting same issue.

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18729609/4886722? Also, it will be beneficial if you can share the `description` value example.

Answer (score 0):

You are feeding Latin encodings 92 / 96 to something that is expecting UTF-8.

Where is that `INSERT` getting its data?  Either fix the source or state that is latin1 (or some similar charset).