# Checking UTF-8 data type 3-byte, or 4-byte Unicode

Tags: java, mysql, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

In my database I get the error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column
```

I use Java and MySQL 5. As I know 4-byte Unicode is legal i Java, but illegal in MySQL 5, I think that it can cause my problem and I want to check type of my data, so here's my question:
How can i check that my UTF-8 data is 3-byte or 4-byte Unicode?

Comment: I suggest looking at your column data type length limit and the size of the data you are trying to insert first. If you are inserting 100K characters into a `VARCHAR` no encoding is at fault.

Comment: I don't think the 4-byte UTF-8 encoded characters are the reason for this problem. The more likely cause is a *n*-character string that takes *m* bytes (with *m* > *n*) when UTF-8 encoded, but should be put into an VARCHAR(*n*).

Comment: @Jon I checked it first, and that wasn't problem I solved it already, but still I think I'll use checking of encoding in future, thaks for help all

Comment: @JoachimSauer FYI MySQL treats `VARCHAR(n) CHARSET utf8` as an `N*3` byte structure, so that's not likely the problem. The problem is likely that OP is simply trying to insert too much data.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encodes everything in the basic multilingual plane (i.e. U+0000 to U+FFFF inclusive) in 1-3 bytes. Therefore, you just need to check whether everything in your string *is* in the BMP.

In Java, that means checking whether any `char` (which is a UTF-16 code unit) is a high or low surrogate character, as Java will use surrogate pairs to encode non-BMP characters:

```
public static boolean isEntirelyInBasicMultilingualPlane(String text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isSurrogate(text.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you do not want to support beyond BMP, you can just strip those characters before handing it to MySQL:

```
public static String withNonBmpStripped( String input ) {
    if( input == null ) throw new IllegalArgumentException("input");
    return input.replaceAll("[^\\u0000-\\uFFFF]", "");
}
```

If you want to support beyond BMP, you need MySQL 5.5+ and you need to change everything that's `utf8`
to `utf8mb4` (collations, charsets ...). But you also need the support for this in the driver that I am
not familiar with. Handling these characters in Java is also a pain because they are spread over 2 `chars`
and thus need special handling in many operations.

Comment: This actually doesn't work well because regexps are evaluated at the level of codepoints, not codeunits. You need to match chars outside range \u0000-\uFFFF (see my answer).

Comment: @jako512 That is surprising since everything else deals with code units :I I have edited it to work with full nonBMP characters but the intent behind original version was to to remove unpaired surrogates as well

Comment: Note that the REGEX may be slightly tweaked for your language. For PHP, use `preg_replace('/[^\x{0000}-\x{FFFF}]/u', '\x{FFFD}', $input);`

Comment: \uF000 - \uFFFF utf8 sequences are still accepted by your regex, but are only used to compose 4 byte chars. So I use the smaller range \u0000 - \uEFFF to remove all 4 byte chars.

Answer (score 6):

Best approach to strip non-BMP charactres in java that I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4035871/489790) is the following:

```
inputString.replaceAll("[^\\u0000-\\uFFFF]", "\uFFFD");
```